# Expose multiple static wsdl files - Spring WS

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am trying to expose 2 different endpoints that are for 2 different static WSDLs using SpringWS and Spring Boot.

The problem that I'm having is declaring two SimpleWsdl11Definition beans and having exposed only one.

These are my configuration files:

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class AWSConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter 
{
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean aMessageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) 
    {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "Av1/*");
    }

    @Bean(name = "AV1")
    public SimpleWsdl11Definition simpleWsdl11Definition() 
    {
        SimpleWsdl11Definition simpleWsdl11Definition = new SimpleWsdl11Definition();
        simpleWsdl11Definition.setWsdl(new ClassPathResource("wsdl/AV1.wsdl"));
        return simpleWsdl11Definition;
    }

    @Bean(name = "ASchema")
    public XsdSchema aSchema() 
    {
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("xsd/A.xsd"));
    }
}
```

and

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class BWSConfig 
{
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean bMessageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) 
    {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "Bv1/*");
    }

    @Bean(name = "BV1")
    public SimpleWsdl11Definition simpleWsdl11Definition() 
    {
        SimpleWsdl11Definition simpleWsdl11Definition = new SimpleWsdl11Definition();
        simpleWsdl11Definition.setWsdl(wsdl/BV1.wsdl"));
        return simpleWsdl11Definition;
    }

    @Bean(name = "bSchema")
    public XsdSchema bSchema() 
    {
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("xsd/BV1.xsd"));
    }
}
```

Only the AV1.wsdl is accessible. Could anyone tell me what am I missing please...

Answer (score 1):

Below bean definition creates a named MessageDispatcherServlet, with an overridden getWsdlDefinition method. This method in the original code selects the wsdl to expose, if url conditions are met, from a spring-initiated list of WsdlDefinitions. The override below makes it possible to select the right one, instead of spring's obscure solution. Manually pair the url with the wsdl definition.

```
@Bean(name = "servlet-a")
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServletA(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServletA(
            ApplicationContext applicationContext,
            @Qualifier("A") final Wsdl11Definition a) {
               MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet(){           
               private static final long serialVersionUID = 8547901522243924975L;
               @Override
               protected WsdlDefinition getWsdlDefinition(HttpServletRequest request) {
                if (yourMethodCheckingForRightExposeUrl(request)) {
                    return a;
                }
                else {
                    return null;
                }
            }           
        };
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setMessageReceiverBeanName("yourSpecificReceiverBeanName");
        ServletRegistrationBean bean = new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/your-endpoint/*"); // star needed to allow any urls
        bean.setName("servlet-a");
        return bean;
    }
}
```

The WsdlDefininition parameter can have the Qualified name 'BV1' in your example.